# Dropzone inside a Django form

Tags: django, forms, dropzone.js, metronic

I'm trying to make a django form in which I want to upload a photo (Dropzone) and enter its title.
I can't send the title field and the photo to my view at the same time.
Could you please help me ? Request.files seems empty.

add.js

```
// DropzoneJs
let myDropzone = new Dropzone("#kt_dropzonejs_example_1", {
    url: "add", // Set the url for your upload script location
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize: 1000, // MB
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function () {
        this.on("success", function (file, response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
      },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value
    }
    });
```

the "url" parameter seems obligatory and gives me problems but necessary with keenthemes metronic

add.htm

```
<form class="form" novalidate="novalidate" id="kt_add_video_form" data-kt-redirect-url="/" action="#"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}  

<!--begin::titre photo group-->
        <div class="row mb-6">
            <!--begin::Label-->
         <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label required fw-semibold fs-6" for="{{ form.caption.id_for_label }}">Titre de la photo</label>
            <!--end::Label-->
            <!--begin::input-->
            <div class="col-lg-9 fv-row">
                {% render_field form.caption class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid mb-3 mb-lg-0" placeholder="Titre"%}
            </div>
            <!--end::input-->
        </div>
    <!--end::titre photo group-->

 <!--begin::Dropzone-->
 <div class="dropzone" id="kt_dropzonejs_example_1">
    <!--begin::Message-->
    <div class="dz-message needsclick">
        <i class="ki-duotone ki-file-up fs-3x"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></i>

        <!--begin::Info-->
        <div class="ms-4">
            <h5 class="fs-6 fw-bold text-gray-500 mb-1">Faites glisser votre photo ici ou cliquer pour les charger.</h5>
            <span class="fs-7 fw-semibold text-gray-500">Jusqu'a 1 Go</span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Info-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--end::Dropzone-->

 <button type="submit"  id="kt_add_video_submit"class="btn btn-primary" data-kt-videos-modal-action="submit">
```

views.py

```
    def post(self, request,  **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        form = forms.PhotoForm(user_flotte, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
    
            file = request.FILES['file']
```

this code returns me "MultiValueDictKeyError at /photos/ajout  'file'

request.FILES seems empty.

Thanks